# What is the correct way to get the first successful result from a "chain" of monadic actions?

Tags: haskell

Is there a canonical way to get the first successful result from `Monad m => [m a]` and to ignore exceptions in this case, BUT to get the first exception if no any success at all? Something like:

```hs
[throwString "e1", throwString "e2"] => ... "e1"
[pure 1, pure 2] => ... 1
[pure 1, throwString "e1", pure 2] => ... 1
```

Because currently I convert `m a` with `tryAny` to `m (Either SomeException a)` then I swap left and right (convert exceptions to strings as well, I prefer strings in the case), then I use `Alt` on them (with some helper-functions) and finally I get `Either a [String]` where `a` is the first successful result (yep, `Left` :) and `[String]` are my exceptions converted to strings. But I don't know if there is a short, convenient, canonical way to do it.

Comment: The notion of "first successful result" doesn't make sense for a general monad. Lots of monads don't involve _yielding results_ in the way `IO` does at all. So, I don't think you'll be able to find something better than converting to `m (Either e a)`, which is exactly what's needed to make the notion meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

[`asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t (f a) -> f a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:asum)

Comment: `>asum [throwString "a", throwString "b", pure 1]` throws instead of to return `1` in some way

Comment: @RandomB What is `throwString` and, if it is typeclass polymorphic, what instance are you using? At least here with the tech I have installed I can't reproduce; e.g. `asum [fail "a", fail "b", pure 1] :: IO Int` cleanly returns `1`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was not clear enough, I use this [throwString](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.4/docs/Control-Exception-Safe.html#v:throwString) but it can be any `IO` throwing an exception (with throwM/throwIO) maybe (well, not sure TBH)

Comment: `>asum [throwIO $ E "a", throwIO $ E "b", pure 1]` raises too (`E` is newtype over String)

Comment: This issue seems to be that the `Alternative` instance for `IO` alternates on `IOError` exceptions *only*.  The function `throwString` in `safe-exceptions` throws a `StringError`, which is an `Exception` defined in that package, unrelated to `IOError`.

Comment: ...and to tag on to @K.A.Buhr's explanation, that means that two ways forward include using a throwing mechanism that does use `IOError` or making a newtype wrapper around `IO` with an alternative `Alternative` instance.